# Gas stoves are specified in terms of BTUs. Why not units of power?

Tags: energy, power

If you go to buy a new gas stove for your kitchen, you will note the main spec of interest is the BTU rating of the burner. Isn't industry making a mistake in using the BTU? The BTU is a unit of energy: the amount of energy to raise one pound of water one degree Fahrenheit. But what is important to the chef is time (speed) of cooking, which is nowhere in the spec. Can someone help me make sense of how BTU is being used by the stove industry here? Shouldn't they specify power instead?

Answer (score 2):

When used to report powers, BTU actually refers to BTU *per hour*, which is a proper power unit.